# Apache Spark master listening on public ip while slaves are on private network

Tags: apache-spark

Master node has 2 nic one with ip `10.0.0.1` and one with ip `192.168.2.1`.
Slaves have ip on `192.168.2.0` network.

I would like to submit programs to the cluster from client on network `10.0.0.0`.

is it possible ?

working with the `spark-env.sh` `SPARK_MASTER_IP` parameter is not enough.

**Edit**:

Even port forwarding is not enough.

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -t nat -i eth1 -p tcp --dport 9999 -j DNAT --to 192.168.2.11:7077

iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp -d 192.168.2.11 --dport 7077 -j ACCEPT
```

and for example `pyspark --master=spark://publicipmaster:9999` returns the error

```
 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system 
    [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@publicipmaster:9999] has failed, 
    address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```